# How to update Core Data and maintain user-saved data?

Tags: sqlite, core-data, user-input, updates

I have an app on the App Store that uses Core Data and I want to make an update. I use a preloaded sqlite file to create the persistentStore. There are two entities in the model, one of which holds user-saved data.

My issue: I want to update the existing Core Data with a new preloaded sqlite, but preserve the user-saved data. Is there a way to merge the new data of the preloaded file with the user-saved data?

The model remains the same; I haven't added any new entities or attributes, so I don't think a migration is appropriate (I could be wrong).

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
   if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
      return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
   }

   NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CreatureData.sqlite"];

   if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
      NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CreatureData" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
      NSLog(@"JUST LOADED COREDATA SQLITE");
      NSError* err = nil;

      if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err]) {
         NSLog(@"Oops, couldn't copy preloaded data");
      }
   } else {
      NSLog(@"Core Data SQLITE already exists");
   }


   NSError *error = nil;
   _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
   if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

       NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
       //abort();
   }

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

EDIT:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CreatureData.sqlite"];
NSURL *secondStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CreatureData" ofType:@"sqlite"]];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
      NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CreatureData" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
      NSLog(@"JUST LOADED COREDATA SQLITE");
      NSError* err = nil;

      if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err]) {
         NSLog(@"Oops, couldn't copy preloaded data");
      }
   }

   NSError *error = nil;
   _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

   NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                             NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES };

   if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:@"UserSavedData" URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
       NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
   }
   if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:@"StaticTableData" URL:secondStoreURL options:options error:&error]) {
       NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple recommends that you separate static and user data, in this case into 2 persistent stores. You could do one of the following:

First and preferable option, you use a separate store for the user data. You need to update the data model to accommodate two stores, so it will be a lightweight migration.

You would then extract the user data on the first startup from the existing sqlite store and store them to your new dynamic store. You can then delete the old sqlite store.

Second option is to keep the current setup. On first run, copy your new file *with a different name*, then extract the user data from the old store and copy it to the new store. Then delete the old store.

Comment: In response to the first option, you said to "update the data model to accommodate two  stores." Does that mean I should split the existing model into two new models (one for the user data and one for the static data)? If so, can you perform a lightweight migration where the new model removes an entity?

Comment: Almost. Yes, it should be possible with a lightweight migration. The trick is to use "Configurations" to address the two stores, but these are referenced in the same model. See [Using Persistent Stores](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingPersistentStores.html) in the Core Data Programming Guide.

Comment: I've been looking at the documentation for Persistent Stores and Managed Object Model Configurations, but I'm still confused. Are you saying I should update the model by adding two Configurations (one for each entity) and then just load each configuration into their own stores? And could you clarify the issue of the two stores being referenced in the same model?

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation again. One model - two configurations, one for each store - one read-only and one read-write store.

Comment: I've done some trial and error after reviewing the documentation, but I'm having trouble with the configurations. I created a new model with a configuration for each entity. When I add the persistent stores to the coordinator, I get an error: "Can't add the same store twice." I'll post code above in an edit.

Comment: Your store URL and secondURL are the same ;-).

Comment: I intend on changing secondStoreURL to a different sqlite with new seed data, but I want to make sure only the user data is being transferred to the new sqlite. Back to your original post, "extract the user data from the existing sqlite store and store them to your new dynamic store." If I'm just adding the stores to the persistentStoreCoordinator, how do I know that it's saving to the new sqlite?